# Do I really need a 1/0 conductor to bond my copper water pipes?

Tags: electrical

I will be replacing my electrical service soon.  I have copper water piping in my house, and my understanding is that it will need to be bonded to the service enclosure.  My service is supplied with 400 kcmil CU ungrounded conductors and will have two feeders with 2/0 CU wires to interior panels.  Based on my understanding of the code, I will need to size the bonding jumper based on the 400 kcmil service conductor.  Table 250.66 says I will need a 1/0 CU bonding jumper.  Is that right?  Why would I need such a large wire (other than the code says so)?  Is the larger service conductor somehow more affected by lightning than a smaller conductor?  I can't imagine this has to do with clearing a fault: There's no way for the copper piping to become energized by the service conductors.
[image]

Comment: Where is your main service disconnect?

Comment: I just found this document from nfpa on grounding; https://www.nfpa.org/-/media/Files/Code-or-topic-fact-sheets/GroundingBondingFactSheet.ashx .  Water pipe bonding comes up on the top of page 3, right hand column.  At first I thought it made it more clear, but now I'm not sure.

Comment: The main service disconnect will be outside.  It's currently inside at two separate panels fed from the meter box.  I plan on installing a 400 amp Siemens meter-main combo with two 200 amp over-current switches.

Comment: Will the main disconnect be on the outside of the house, or on a pole somewhere in the yard?

Comment: Attached to the outside of the house.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, but if you're still looking at this, is your water service line (the underground pipe from the street to the house) metal or plastic?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - No worries at all.  The water service from the street is pvc, but the copper that goes under the slab and throughout the house is copper.  I don't know the extent the copper pipe is underground, though - whether it is sleaved, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### These tables are grounded in fault and fusing currents

Water pipe bonding jumper sizing is based on Table 250.102(C)(1) in the NEC, which indeed calls out a 1/0 copper bonding jumper for your 400kcmil copper service.  As to why it does so? This table (and others in Article 250) are based on the *fusing current* capacity of the bond vs. the *fault current* delivery capacity expected of the power-carrying conductors (in your case, the service entrance conductors).  Furthermore, it's assumed that these jumpers may have to carry fault current from points upstream of the main disconnect, hence the conservative sizing as the utility's fuses are not going to clear the fault as quickly.

Answer (score 0):

NEC 250.66(A) grounding electrode conductor shall not be required to be larger than 6AWG copper wire or 4AWG aluminum wire

Comment: Hey Ed, thanks for answering. I'm bonding the water pipe to the service equipment through the grounding electrode conductor, so I can't use that rule.  You could also think of the water pipe as a supplemental grounding electrode (though I'm not sure it runs a full 10 feet underground, hence the two grounding rods.  Since it's not a grounding rod, that exception does not apply.